# status bar aligns vertically in ipad device

Tags: objective-c, ipad, statusbar

Status bar displays perfectly on top(horizontally)in simulator but it aligns vertically at the edge of screen (against the most conventional method of appearing at the upper edge of device screen)in the ipad device.shouldAutoRotatetoInterfaceOrientation method is not implemented in any controller.

What might be the problem and how can i fix this?

Comment: Is your app configured to allow only one orientation? and do you set the device orientation, or do you apply CGAffineTransform to any views in order to get them (for example) in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the application is spreaded widely so the mode was portrait although status bar is set as landscape.I did portrait to status bar and In viewWillAppear add [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:animated]

Comment: Hello Vani, welcome to StackOverflow, if you have any additional information, please edit your question, rather than posting an answer.

thank you, and good luck :)